# Convert nullable string to nullable int in c#

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

I have variable with below

```
  int? a=null ;
    
  string? b= null;
```

I need to assign a=b ;

What is best way to assign in c# 9

```
a= Convert.ToInt32(b);
```

It is assigning 0 ..hw to assign null if string also null.. i need to know in c# 9

**EDIT: Thanks to @john.. i ended up with below code**

```
  if(b is not null) 
     a = Convert.ToInt32(b);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would just be very explicit about it:

```cs
int? a = b is null ? null : Convert.ToInt32(b);
```